# dom parser extract link and specific text from a non semantic html page(no ids or classes etc)

Tags: php, html, dom, extract

I have an html page with content like this:

```
<a href="coord/ag13.dat">ag13.dat</a>\ Drela AG13 airfoil \<a href="afplots/ag13.gif">ag13.gif</a>\ \ \ <a href="ref/misc_refs.html#3">Ref [3]</a><br>
```

I  need to extract  the text  "\ Drela AG13 airfoil \" . How can I achieve this?
So far, I have managed to extract the content of the links which may be useful for me

```
    include "simple_html_dom.php";

    $html = file_get_html('http://aerospace.illinois.edu/m-selig/ads/coord_database.html');
    foreach($html->find('a[href*=coord\/]') as $element) 
    echo $element->href. ;
```

p.s:I have never been involved in a project like this so it is all new for me.

Comment: You need to query the text nodes in between the anchors; not sure how simpleHtmlDom does that.

Comment: the find is going to just return your `<a>` tag. You need to exploit the fact that every node in the DOM tree "knows" where it is, and get the SIBLING textnode of the matched `<a>`'s.

Comment: @user2639493 do you have any problems using DOMDocument or SimpleXML for the task? Just wondering because simple html dom is so old and outdated by newer and better libraries that I don't understand why people are still attached to it.

Comment: @user2639493 thanks for your suggestion..as I said it is all new for me so I found it easy to start with the simple dom. I didn t even know that it is old :P

Comment: Btw., HTML is not necessarily “non semantic” just because it does not contain ids/classes on the elements _you_ are interested in ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `innertext`, like this:

```
foreach($html->find('a[href*=coord\/]') as $element) 
    echo $element->innertext. '<br>';
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but we have the same result. I do not need the link I need the text after the first link "\ Drela AG13 airfoil \".